# The report definition has an invalid target namespace ISSUE

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2017, report, rdlc, report-designer

IDE : VS Studio 2017
DB : Oracle SQL

I keep on having this kind of error

[image: ERROR PROMPT]

Things I do resolving this but nothing helps me w/ my issue :

- I already add the latest version (140.1000.523) of  Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms
- I also tried to find the TargetServerVersion but seems only applicable to those who use Report Server Project and I'm not using it (The right-click properties then change TargetServerVersion to "SQL Server 2008 or later"
- I also change my **...reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition** into **...reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition** at xmlns and this not recommended since I keep on adjusting it in back-end whenever I change something in report.

Comment: Hi Francis, is this still an open issue? Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 seems to emit the 2016 RDL schema, as you've noted. The Microsoft Report Viewer 2016 control (Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms, v14.x) should render the 2016 RDL OK. Might you share the RDL you're parsing? Is it just this one RDLC or all of them?

Comment: Not correct, I have a colleague with VS2017 version 15.9.7. When he modifies the report RDL stays as 2008.